# Round off Numbers

Tags: matlab

I have matrix `100*100` (row*column) and it contains numbers like `0.00051,0.00052,0.00056` and so on. I tried to round off these numbers but the problem is
using `round(X)` will only give `"0"`. I want to round off numbers so,

```
0.00051 become 0.0005
0.00052 become 0.0005
0.00056 become 0.0006
```

Thanks

Comment: try Round to Specified Number of Decimal Digits

Round pi to the nearest 4 decimal digits.

Y = round(pi,4)

Answer (score 0):

This exact question is asked on MATLAB Central here, and answered by Roger Stafford:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/169196?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

To steal his answer for your convenience:

> To actually alter the number n to the nearest four place decimal, do:
>
> m = 4; % Number of significant decimals
>   k = floor(log10(abs(n)))-m+1;
>   n2 = round(n/10^k)*10^k;

Alternatively, you could get roundn(x,n) off the Matlab file exchange and do roundn(x,-4).
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37067-roundn-x-n--returns-x-rounded-to-n-digits

And now for the simple solution, suggested by Mohamed: use round(x,4), as per the Matlab documentation.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html

This is all one quick google search away. Please do research in the future.